# Choose attributes for each quantity on a configurable product in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7, configurable-product

I need on Magento 1.7 to let the user choose attributes for each quantity in a configurable product.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customer can select one product at a time and add them to shopping cart by selecting different attribute each time.

What you can do is let the customer stay on the product details page even after adding products to the cart(means, don't redirect them to shopping cart). For setting this property follow the path given below,

> **Admin > System > Configuration > Default Config > Sales > Checkout >
>   Shopping Cart > “After adding a product redirect to shopping cart”** and
>   set it to **NO**

This way is also helpful when a customer want to add different quantity with same attribute, suppose the customer wants 3 RED Small Reebok T-shirt, 2 Black XL Reebok T-shirt, 4 Green L Reebok T-shirt. The customer can add the desired quantity with a particular attribute of the same product and still remains in the same Product Details page.

This is a very handy functionality of Magento.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution doesn't match with my "wannabe" customer experience. I'm looking for something confortable for a football team order ( 11 players with Size and custom name for each shirt )

Comment: How it doesn't meets the need ? The customer Puts the Custom Name and the desired size One at a time and adds them to the shopping cart keeping the quantity as 1. You can use Ajax to make the process more simple though.